# Javascript atob(str) equivilent in c#

Tags: c#, javascript

I did this:

```
 byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
 string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
 Console.WriteLine(decodedString);
```

but got `Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.`

In javascript using `atob(str)` gives me the right decoded str.

javascript console:

```
atob("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")
"{"iss":"https://identity-staging.ascend.xyz","aud":"https://identity-staging.ascend.xyz/resources","client_id":"6994A4A8-0E65-4FED-A82B-C684A0DD1758","scope":["openid","profile","sub.read","data.write","data.read","alg.execute"],"sub":"377c095b-783b-47e7-97b1-5aed98c038fc","amr":"external","auth_time":1407615507,"idp":"https://sts.windows.net/0840c760-6f7b-4556-b337-8c090e2d458d/","name":"pks@ascend.xyz","exp":1407836711,"nbf":1407833111}"
```

Comment: what is `parts`? a string array?

Comment: I will update the question to leave that out. yes its a array. the parts[1] is the same string i tested with in javascript that works

Comment: how is the string defined, are you sure the string is properly escaped?

Comment: I just copy pasted the same string that i tested in javascript into c# code. str = "my_jwt_token"; Will update the question again to show code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    var str = "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";
    int mod4 = str.Length % 4;
    if (mod4 > 0)
    {
        str += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
    }
```

solved it in c#

Comment: would I need to use this on both encoding and decoding sides? or just decoding?

Comment: just for decoding, its due to that base64 string can omit the == at the end, but c# expect the length to be divisible by 4 (hence the often == at the end).

Comment: This fixes a broken encoded input string like fC4wMDI0MDIyNYMyNTczRIrXALxhHLMzMx and convert it to a valid encoded fC4wMDI0MDIyNYMyNTczRIrXALxhHLMzMx==. Now I am able to use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(encoedString))`

Answer (score 10):

Use **javascript's window.btoa** function to encode the string in Base 64 Format in Javascript Frontend UI. To decode back same string in C# (the equivalent of **javascript's window.atob** function) please see the following code.

*(Most probably you are trying to post back data (HTML in most cases as it requires btoa encoding to ensure the best compatibility)) back to the controller or you might creating custom basic basic authentication filter on server side)*

```
string base64Encoded = "YmFzZTY0IGVuY29kZWQgc3RyaW5n";
string base64Decoded;
byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);
base64Decoded = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
Console.WriteLine(base64Decoded)
```

You can see its working sample at https://dotnetfiddle.net/abxwSw

Comment: Thank you ! its working like  a charm...Thanks