# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string during decoding

Tags: c#, angular, encoding, decoding, typescript2.0

In my current project development I was faced the issue of converting the base64 to string at my API side.

before that I did convert the string to base64 in angular 2 application using typescript code like this below.

```
    let encodessn = window.btoa(vehicleInfo.SSN);
    console.log(encodessn);
```

After make HTTP Post request with above data to my API then I am trying convert the base64 string to normal string like this below lines of code.

```
 vehicleInfoTable.SSN= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(s));
```

After Executed the above line of code it gives the exception like "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."

I think I am using different algorithms for converting string to base64 and vice versa.

Can you please tell me where did I mistake and tell me how to encode the string in typescript and how to decode the same encoded string using C#.

-Pradeep

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260371/javascript-atobstr-equivilent-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks, it resolved my issue.